# KVM switch triggers randomly on any operations with VirtualBox windows

Tags: usb, virtualbox, kvm-switch

I would like to try to make this KVM switch unavailable for guest operating system.

Unfortunately, [Oracle documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-usb) is not clear. They probably use terms "local", "remote", "guest" and "host" interchangeably. For example, they have setting `Remote` which is not clear what it does:

[image]

They say

*As an example, you could create a new USB filter and specify a vendor ID of 046d (Logitech, Inc), a manufacturer index of 1, and **"not remote"**. Then any USB devices on the host system produced by Logitech, Inc with a manufacturer index of 1 will **be visible** to the guest system.*

then probably "Remote" means device should not be visible, but it apparently does not help.

Comment: The [`Remote`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#usb-over-rdp) option is for accessing USB devices on another (remote) computer via VRDP. Adding a filter is specifically to enable automatic access to the device from the guest so you don't have manually enable it, it does not disable access to it .. not sure why your KVM would be triggering from a VM though ..?

Comment: @txtechhelp it probably reacts on Virtualbox probe or something

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution to this one!

http://howtosavethings.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-save-your-kvm-switch-from.html

Cliff Notes Version:  The NumLock is messing it up.  Click OUTSIDE the VM (on host computer desktop), set NumLock how you want it.  Click back INSIDE the VM and set THAT computer's NumLock (preferably the same).  Then, problem solved (at least it was in MY case...)